# Saml overview and implementations

Tags: authentication, single-sign-on, saml, saml-2.0

I am a beginner for saml authentication. I can understand the concepts and theme. But in real time, I do not know how to implement and code it.

> What are all needed? How to code for the saml authentication? What technology needed? **How many servers/websites needed?** Which will be the service provider and identity provider. I do not know the procedure to code.

**What are the prerequisites should i know?**

I referred http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/Post2.0/sstc-saml-tech-overview-2.0-cd-02.html#1.Introduction|outline. But it is quite confusing. I could not get a clear idea to implement for my own.

> 1. What are the series of instructions to implement SAML authentication
>      for my own sever/website?
> 2. Which will be the IDENTITY provider(Authorization server) and
>      SERVICE provider?
> 3. How websites put it in service provider(Resource server) and saml authentication given?
> 4. How credentials stored and token response generated in the identity
>      provider.
> 5. How to implement as a code and what are needed to create?

Please help me.. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified the language but on the client side, you need a SAML stack.

Refer [SAML : SAML connectivity / toolkit](http://nzpcmad.blogspot.co.nz/2013/06/saml-saml-connectivity-toolkit.html).

On the server side, you need an IDP.

This could be ADFS, shibboleth, identityserver or an IDaaS product like Auth0 or Okta.

Comment: thanks a lot... I use angular 4 at front end and node js for backend. is this possible?My objective is to set up my own custom SAML application. Could you please provide more detail about this?